# why does entity framework seem to update unchanged entities

Tags: entity-framework

Posting this here despite having found the solution already so people can find it if anyone has the same problem.

Entity framework seemed to update properties that were only linked to the actually changed entity via navigation properties, which had me quite confused.

A similar example for clarification: Let's take an order for 3 kgs of sugar. That order has an ID, an amount, a product ID giving it a virtual product (sugar), and a customer ID giving it a virtual customer. While saving the order, the customer and the product were getting updated in the DB too.

I was trying to find answers to questions like "why are navigation properties set as modified", "why are unchanged child entities updated too", and so on.

Comment: EF would update only when an entity it tracks in the context is set to `EntityState.Modified`, perhaps including the code you used to save/update would shed light on your problem?

Answer (score 0):

A thorough debugging showed that the actual reason was me using the classes at a different point in the same controller action - for example, I migh want to send out a notification about the order by E-Mail, so I'm calling a Mail action with a DTO (data transfer object) giving it the relevant information for the mail, looking somewhat like this:

```
public class MailDTO {
    public Order order { get; set; }
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
    public Product product { get; set; }
}
```

Since the actual customer entity has lots of information that the Mail doesn't need, I created a new Customer object with just the relevant information to put into that DTO. That's where the problem was - that new customer entity was being tracked by the framework, so when I called the savechanges(async) function, the framework tried to write that to the DB too.

Hope this helps someone else to not waste time looking for an error in all the wrong places ;)